# Redirecting domain without visibility to the user

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a server with 2 domains parked on it. For example `abc.com` and `xyz.com`.

The content of my CMS (WP) is on `abc.com/content/`.

I want to redirect user calling `xyz.com` to the `abc.com/content` while preserving the `abc.com` domain.

Other example:
If I call `xyz.com/example-page` it should redirect on `abc.com/content/example-page` without let user see the `abc.com` domain.

I have the possibility to use mod_rewrite and/or redirect by confixx panel.

Comment: If you go to `xyz.com` do you have the same content as `abc.com` ? I mean, do your domains have the same document root on the server ?

Comment: yes at moment both points to /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in document root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?xyz\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!content/).*)$ /content/$1 [L]
```

Don't forget to enable *mod_rewrite* and check if `htaccess` files are allowed in your Apache configuration